# displaying characters with colors

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I'm trying to create a Javascript function that randomly assigns the characters in a string to a set of colors I have chosen. I'm not quite sure how to select a character in the string and assign it a color

Here is my code:

```
    <script>
        function Rainbow(x,chosencolor) {
            var mystring = String(x);                                              @* convert to string*@
            var Stringlength = mystring.lenth;                                     @* length fo string *@
            var rainbowstring = new Array(Stringlength);                           @* create array of appropriate size*@
            var counter = 0;

            while (counter < Stringlength) {
                var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);                     @* random number generator --> 11 means 0-10 *@         

                  switch (randomnumber) {
                    case 0:

                        break;
                    case 1:

                        break;
                    case 2:

                        break;
                    case 3:

                        break;
                    case 4:

                        break;
                    case 5:

                        break;
                    case 6:

                        break;
                    case 7:

                        break;
                    case 8:

                        break;
                    case 9:

                        break;
                }
                rainbowstring[counter] = chosencolor;                              @* assign color *@
                counter++;                                                         @* increment *@
            }
     }

        @* need something that generates colors *@
        @* assigns colors to text *@

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
function Rainbow(x,chosencolor) {
  var mystring = String(x);                                              @* convert to string*@
 var Stringlength = mystring.lenth;                                     @* length fo string *@
 var rainbowstring = new Array(Stringlength);                           @* create array of appropriate size*@
var counter = 0;
var clr, ltr;
  while (counter < Stringlength) {
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);                     @* random number generator --> 11 means 0-10 *@   
    ltr = mystring.charAt(counter); //--- get the current letter      
    switch (randomnumber) {
        case 0: clr='#f00'; break;
        case 1: clr='#0f0'; break;
        case 2: clr='#00f'; break;
        case 3: clr='#000'; break;
        case 4: clr='#fff'; break;
        case 5: break;
        case 6: break;
        case 7: break;
        case 8: break;
        case 9: break;
     }
     rainbowstring[counter] = "<span style='color:"+clr+"'>"+ltr+"</span>";                              @* assign color *@
     counter++;                                                         @* increment *@
   }
}
</script>
```